# Why do I have to use a type assertion when logically the type should be known?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm encountering a scenario (below) where logically the type of an object can be determined but I am forced to use a type assertion anyway, and even seem to have to create 'pre-typed' dummy variables to access the type-specific properties correctly. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

```
export type EventTypeItem =
    event1 |
    event2;

enum Event {
    Event1,
    Event2
}

interface event1 {
    readonly id: string;
}

interface event2 {
    readonly caller: ICaller;
}

interface ICaller {
    readonly id: string;
}


export interface IEvent {
    readonly eventItem: EventTypeItem;
    readonly eventType: Event;
}

// IEvent event gets passed to component

let exampleUnknownEvent: IEvent; // to access id - we'd either follow '.id' or '.caller.id'
// but we don't know before hand what Event this will be

// within some function

const x = exampleUnknownEvent as event1; // this seems like an unnecessary assignment just to type assert
const y = exampleUnknownEvent as event2; // this seems like an unnecessary assignment just to type assert

if (exampleUnknownEvent.eventType === Event.Event2) {
    return x.caller.id;
} // I'd rather return exampleUnknownEvent.caller.id as we've established type in 'if'
  //   e.g. exampleUnkownEvent.caller.id as event2
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is typeguarding, and it should work. Here's a simpler version, without the extra variables:

```js
export type EventTypeItem = event1 | event2;

enum Event {
    Event1,
    Event2
}

interface event1 {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly event: Event.Event1
}
interface event2 {
    readonly caller: ICaller;
    readonly event: Event.Event2
}

interface ICaller {
    readonly id: string;
}

export interface IEvent {
    readonly eventItem: EventTypeItem;
}

let exampleUnknownEvent: IEvent = /* get your event here */

if (exampleUnknownEvent.eventItem.event === Event.Event1) {
    console.log(exampleUnknownEvent.eventItem.id);
} else {
    console.log(exampleUnknownEvent.eventItem.caller.id);
}
```

What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using 3.4.1. Looking at your version (thanks btw) made me realise my code wasn't accurate - sorry. I've updated my example to provide the event type on the generic IEvent object, which is being checked by the if statement. As the event type is now not directly on the specific event  type, I guess the type inference is lost.